# mvc3 razor html.actionlink linktext part of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view I want to display an Html.ActionLink if a ViewBag dynamic variable is true and show a Html.Label if that same variable is false.

I also want the ActionLink LinkText to be based on the value of a property in my Model.
i.e. item.Description

so it should be

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "MyAction")
```

or

```
@Html.LabelFor(item.Description)
```

How do I get this to work?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if((bool)ViewBag.isTrue){
   @Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "MyAction")
}
else{
 @Html.LabelFor(item => item.Description)
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I think I mistakenly said item.Description I meant to say it's another ViewBag dynamic Expression instead.  Which of course @Html.ActionLink doesn't seem to liked in the spot of the LinkText

Comment: ok nm.  I simply had to cast it as string (string) in front of ViewBag.Description.